# Problems encrypting SD card

Tags: 14.04, encryption, sd-card

I've tried a couple of times to encrypt a 1GB SD card using Disk Utility. I thought all went well until I tried to unlock it. When I enter the passcode, it looks as if the device is opened up, but then I get a message:

This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "[Disk name]"

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Edit: I should add, I formatted the SD on a Lubuntu 14.04 laptop and tried to open it on another laptop that's running regular Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage (at the very bottom of the page):

> The first time the encrypted filesystem is mounted, the ownership of the root folder of the device will need to be changed to the current user as follows:
>
> ```
> sudo chown naaman:naaman /media/disk
> ```
>
> where naaman is the username and the second naaman is the group name

This should not be an issue when using Disk Utility, but it is the first place to try.

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: Did you run the command as written?  Aside from changing the username, you also need to use the correct directory.  Check with mount to verify where it is mounted (it should be something like /media/username/[Disk Name]

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick. Much obliged!